# Why is my code throwing an IllegalMonitorStateException?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand how threads work in Java. Hence I wrote a small piece of code where by I create two threads, one printing all odd numbers and other printing even numbers, and trying to synchronize between them so that all the numbers are printed in order.

```
public class Main 
{

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Main lock = new Main();

        Test t1 = new Test(1, lock);

        Test t2 = new Test(2, lock);

        synchronized(lock){

            (new Thread(t1)).start();
            (new Thread(t2)).start();

        }


    }

}
```

---

```
public class Test implements Runnable {


    int n;
    Main lock;

    public Test(int newN, Main lockObj){
        this.n = newN;
        this.lock = lockObj;
    }


    public void run() {


        while(true){

            if (n != 1){
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            n = n + 2;

            System.out.println(n);

            lock.notify();

        }


    }


}
```

Can someone please help understand what the underlying problem is?

Comment: It's a little bizarre to use an instance of `Main` as the lock object.  No harm in it, but It would be more conventional to say `Object lock = new Object()`.  Being more conventional becomes important when you start working with other developers.  They will be happier to work with you if your code does not look strange.

Comment: It's important to note that `wait()` must always be called inside a tight loop that checks the condition being awaited.  The method's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) has full details and an example.

Answer (score 6):

You have three threads, the `main` thread, `t1` and `t2`.  The thread ***owning*** the lock can use actions `notify`, `notifyAll` and `wait`.  In this case the `main` thread owns the lock not `t1` or `t2`.

You will need to synchronize within the `run` method of each thread to be able to `wait`.

---

Here is an example of what I mean by `synchronizing` in the `run` method.

Any operation that happens from the `run` method after you start the thread will be done by that thread running.  So when you try and `wait` you will want to make sure the thread owns the lock, you can do this by synchronizing it in the run method.

```
public void run() {
     synchronized(lock){
         while(true){
            if (n != 1){
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
            n = n + 2;
            System.out.println(n);
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am synchronizing within the `run` method so that `t1` and `t2` own the locks while notifying or waiting.

Comment: I tried removing lock from the `main` thread and creating a static lock (of Main class) in Test, but got the same result.

Any ideas as to how I can approach to solve the particular problem at hand given the class structure remains the same?

Comment: As my last sentence said.  You have to `synchronize` within the `run` method of each separate thread.  Not within the `main` method.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "the main thread owns the lock".  That is one possibility, but since the main thread is not synchronized with the other two, and since it only owns the lock for a brief moment, it's also quite possible that the main thread has already released the lock and terminated before either of the other two threads enters the Test#run() method.

Comment: It's not enough just to tell the noob to use `synchronized`. You should also say _where_ to put it.  In this case, that would be, around the while() loop in the run() method.

Comment: @jameslarge Yea, I tried to lead the OP into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not help you understanding the low-level threading mechanics, but for your case it would make sense to use a [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) with a barrierAction.

Make both treads wait on the barrier after processing `n = n + 2`, let the barrierAction sysout both thread's current `n`, repeat.